# Matching methods from LWP::UserAgent to Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent, mojo-useragent

I need to convert LWP::UserAgent to Mojo::UserAgent to support async calls. Problem is I couldn't find the exact methods that matches the LWP::UserAgent methods below, for example, how do I convert the following LWP methods over to Mojo's? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent ;

$ua->protocols_allowed( [ 'http', 'https' ] );

$ua->ssl_opts( 
 SSL_version=>'TLSv12', 
 verify_hostname=>0,  
 SSL_verify_mode=>SSL_VERIFY_NONE, 
 SSL_ca_file=>'ca_file.crt',
 SSL_cert_file=>'cert_file.crt',
 SSL_key_file=>'key_file.key',
 SSL_passwd_cb=> sub { return 'psswd'; }
);

$ua->credentials( $host_port, $realm, $user, $password ) ;

$ua->timeout( $timeOut ) ;

$ua->proxy( $theProxy ) ;

$ua->request( $requestObj );
```

Answer (score 1):

By reading the documentation pages for [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent), here is what I can see:

- `$ua->protocols_allowed()` : This function is not available in `Mojo::UserAgent`
- `SSL_version` : can be set for `Mojo::UserAgent` by calling `IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_version()`
- `verify_hostname` : If verification is wanted, it can be called explicitly by calling `IO::Socket::SSL::verify_hostname()`
- `SSL_verify_mode` : Can be set by calling `IO::Socket::SSL::set_defaults(SSL_verify_mode => $mode)`
- `SSL_ca_file` : `Mojo::UserAgent` has a method `$ua->ca()` that can be used.
- `SSL_cert_file` : `Mojo::UserAgent` has a method `$ua->cert()` that can be used
- `SSL_key_file` : `Mojo::UserAgent` has a method `$ua->key()` that can be used
- `SSL_passwd_cb` : Can be set by calling `IO::Socket::SSL::set_defaults(SSL_passwd_cb => $cb)`
- `$ua->credentials` : I think these can be set by constructing a [Mojo::URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL) object and passing it to the relevant request method.
- `$ua->timeout()` :  `Mojo::UserAgent` has a method `$ua->connect_timeout()` that can be used
- `$ua->proxy()` : `Mojo::UserAgent` has a method `$ua->proxy()` that can be used.
- `$ua->request()` : `Mojo::UserAgent` has a methods `$ua->start()` and `$ua->start_p()` that can be used.